# unable to change the dimensions of UI controls and fontsize of textblocks based on resolution for windows store apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

i'm new to windows store app development. I have developed a application that works and looks fine on standard resolution.

Now I want to change the fontsize, width , height of controls based on screen resolution.

is there any generic way to implement my requirement.

Thanks in advance,

harsha

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 will automatically use more pixels to render UI elements in your app when it is viewed on a higher pixel density display. The elements will have a same size on the screen, they will just appear smoother.

However, Windows won't interprolate bitmaps present in your UI. To work around that, you can provide 3 different image files for every bitmap used in your app, and Windows will select the one with the best resolution for the pixel density of device.

See here for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods for managing different resolutions on Windows 8 so your app will look great from 10" screens to 27" displays. There is the Fixed Layout and the Adaptive Layout.

It sounds like you want to use the Fixed Layout, this will make your app that looks good at the standard resolutions and make that fill the entire screen on a 27" display rather than only displaying in the top left corner which is the standard behavior. The key to this method is the Viewbox control. Pretty much you wrap your entire page in a Viewbox control and it scales your content appropriately. You still need to take care of managing your layout in snapped and filled scenarios and assign the width/height of your viewbox and other controls to fit those.

With the Adaptive Layout method, you would include more content on the larger resolutions.

The best page I can point you to on these concepts is the Guidelines for scaling to screens ->
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx

I've heard it suggested that you should make sure your design uses 5 pixel units to ensure that the scaling works properly in line with the app layout guidelines -> 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh872191.aspx